# Client-Server program assigning different ports using python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I wrote a client program where i am trying to bind to the host machine and port and trying to run the same program in different machine to check if server can handle multiple clients but i am getting error.

```
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

The goal is using same machine but with more ports to simulate clients like more than 10 to 1000. But initially i failed to run after all two parallel client program on same machine.

I tried to change port and binded to it and run it other terminal but it doesn't work.

Can someone please give a code example thanks.

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
import socket
from socket import *
import time
from time import ctime

def con_server(Host,port):
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    host='192.168.1.xx'
    por=5060
    ad=(host,por)
    sock.bind(ad)
    address=(Host,port)
    sock.sendto("connection".encode(),address)
    data,server=sock.recvfrom(4096)
    data=data.decode()
    print('Client:' +data)


if __name__=="__main__":
    t2=threading.Thread(target=con_server,name='con_servr',args=("192.168.1.cc,4242))
    t2.start()
    t2.join()
```

Edited client:

```
import socket

def create_sock():
    for port in range(6000,7000):
        sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.bind(("localhost", port))
        host = "localhost"
        port = 4242
        address = (host, port)
        import time
        print("sendtime",time.clock())
        sock.sendto("connection".encode(), address)
        data, server = sock.recvfrom(4096)
        print("receivetime",time.clock())
        data = data.decode()
        print('Client:' + data)

if __name__=="__main__":
    create_sock()
```

I wrote this client program to generate multiple clients for different port. Do you think its a right way to do?

Comment: There is no need for the client to explicitly call bind with a hard-coded address, so don't do that. Just let it implicitly bind to an available port when `sendto(...)` is first called.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you are binding the client to a specific address, but that's probably not what you want. Here is an example with multiple threads showing how the first call to `sendto` causes the socket to be bound to an available local port.

```py
import socket
import threading


def con_server(server_host, server_port, thread_num):
    server_address = (server_host, server_port)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print(sock.getsockname())
    sock.sendto(f"connection{thread_num}".encode("utf-8"), server_address)
    print(sock.getsockname())
    data = sock.recv(4096)
    data = data.decode()
    print('Client:' + data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # SERVER_ADDR = ("192.168.1.cc", 4242)
    SERVER_ADDR = ("localhost", 4242)
    threads = []
    for thread_num in range(30):
        thread_args = (SERVER_ADDR[0], SERVER_ADDR[1], thread_num)
        t = threading.Thread(target=con_server, name='con_servr', args=thread_args)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Comment: please check my updated client. Do you think its a good way to do or its better to follow the way you suggested.

Comment: I use python 3.5, f" is not supported. Is there any replacement to it in your code? Thanks